# React tetris. Function always returns false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react project I have 2D array which contains numbers.
I also have the `collisionCheck` function which loop through it and check certain values. I want it to return `true` and exit function when it finds value  other than zero, but it always returns `false`.  Can someone please help me to understand why?

```
collisionCheck = (yPos, xPos) => {
        this.state.board.forEach((row, y) => row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if((y === yPos && x === xPos && value != 0)) return true; 

        }))
    }
```

```
this.state = {
            board: [
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            ],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `forEach` call to `some`:

```
collisionCheck = (yPos, xPos) => {
  return this.state.board.some((row, y) => row.some((value, x) => (y === yPos && x === xPos && value != 0)));
}
```